# Check server response after a iron-form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, polymer

I am submitting a form using iron-form. However, when the server responds, I want to see what the response is so that I can:

- Either close the form (if everything was OK)
- Or highlight the "broken" fields (if the response was an error)

I realise I can easily listen to `iron-form-error` to see if there were any problems. The error comes back as Json, where I have key/value where the key is the field name, and the value is the error message.

In case the response was indeed an error, do I have to go through the response manually? Or is there a shorthand version to display the error messages automagically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing any pre-validation with validators attached to the inputs?  These will provide error messages that you have put in the error-message attribute of the input.  When the response comes back you can just set the paper-input to invalid.

I have a password change dialog that is like this.  It uses a validator to check that password 1 and password 2 are the same, but the server also checks this too.  In this case it sends a valid json response (ie not an error) with the response json object containing an field that tells me that particular field is wrong (as a boolean).  Here is a fragment of my response after earlier I have done `var response = e.detail.response;`

```
  if (response.status) {
    this.$.profiledialog.close();
    this._setNopass(false);  //just get this back to its default state
  } else {
    if (!response.passwd1) {
      if (response.passwd2) {
        this.$.pw1.invalid = true;
        this.$.pw1.focus();
      } else {
        throw new Error('Profile Update Server Failure');
      }
    }
    if (!response.passwd2) {
      this.$.pw2.invalid = true;
      this.$.pw2.focus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This confirms what I was thinking -- I need to get things done by hand, setting them as invalid. I am working on a wrapper widget that, given a form and an iron-ajax form, will actually check the response from the server and set the right field as "invalid"...